# spark 2.0 - java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jupyter": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using jupyter notebooks to try spark.

Once in my notetbook I try a Kmean:

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from sklearn               import datasets
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("PythonKMeansExample")\
        .getOrCreate()

iris       = datasets.load_iris()
pd_df      = pd.DataFrame(iris['data'])
spark_df   = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df, ["features"])
estimator  = KMeans(k=3, seed=1)
```

Everything goes fine, then I fit the model :

```
estimator.fit(spark_df)
```

And I got an error :

```
16/08/16 22:39:58 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 24)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jupyter": error=2, No such file or directory

Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Where is spark looking for Jupyter ? 
Why can't it find it if I can use jupyter notebook ?
What to do ?..

Answer (score 5):

as code says in      https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/context.py#L180

```
self.pythonExec = os.environ.get("PYSPARK_PYTHON", 'python')
```

so I think this error is caused by env variable `PYSPARK_PYTHON`, it indicates that python location of each spark node,  when pyspark started, `PYSPARK_PYTHON` which is from sys env will be injected to all sparknodes, so that

1. it can be solved by

   ```
   export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
   ```

   which are the same version on diff nodes. and then start:

   ```
   pyspark
   ```
2. if there is diff versions of python among local and diff nodes of cluster, another version conflicts error will occur.
3. the version of the interactive python which you work in should be the same version with other nodes in cluster.

Comment: I meet the same error when run spark on yarn. `export PYSPARK_PYTHON` is not useful on my case, any way to solve it ?